# SignalR and Tunnelling

Tags: signalr, http-tunneling

There is my configuration:

```
client app->WCF service (http://serverhost:8082 + SignalR service http://serverhost:8083)
```

I use bdtunnel from Sebastien Lebreton (https://github.com/sailro/Bdtunnel)

```
client app->bdtunnel:8080 (it forwards: localhost:8182->server:8082)->WCF service
```

It works fine.

The question is: is it possible to forward SignalR connection via the same tunnel on port 8080?

Comment: I don't know answer to your question and did not use Bdtunnel but what's the point of tunneling HTTP (long polling, serverSentEvents) over HTTP? I don't think Websocket transport can be tunneled like this at all...

Comment: It may be useful when for example available 80, 443, 8080 ports only but behind of firewall some services work on other ports

Comment: In that case you should try the longPolling transport - I think it has the biggest chance to work.

Comment: SignalR uses LongPolling too. But I already use SignalR in my service and the task is how client app can work with it via tunnel

Comment: What I am saying is that if SignalR can work at all with tunneling the SignalR longPolling transport will be the easiest to tunnel. In other words - instead of relying on the client to select the transport force the SignalR client to use the longPolling transport.

Comment: ah, I see. How SignalR server can force to select longpolling transport?